# "Could not find Cortex-M device in the JTAG chain!" (TM4C123g)

Tags: microcontroller, arm, tm4c123g

The board was working fine but all of the sudden I can't download any code on it from Keil.
Whenever I try to download code on the board, I get

"Could not find Cortex-M device in the JTAG chain!
Please check the JTAG cable and connection devices"

I tried a couple of different cables but didn't work. 
What can be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the suggestion from the Keil website:

> No Cortex-M Device found in JTAG chain No Cortex-M processor-based
>   device detected (using JTAG). Device is not connected, not powered, or
>   the debug interface is not working. Enable the SWJ switch in the ULINK
>   USB-JTAG/SWD Adapter section of the Target Driver Setup - Debug
>   dialog.

Check you have power to the device, power cycle the probe, check the probe settings. If the target is crashed, its possible that you'd see this. Try lowering the JTAG frequency. Check the probe has a correct target voltage connection.

The Keil forums might have some more iseas you can try.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you please tell me how to "Enable the SWJ switch in the ULINK USB-JTAG/SWD Adapter section of the Target Driver Setup - Debug dialog."?

Comment: Start here, and read  the Keil documentation http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulink2/ulink2_ctx_jtag_adapter.htm If you ask in the Keil forums, youu'll find people more familiar with these tools.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Tried various proposed solutions, in the end what worked for me was the solution proposed by **splatapus** on the TI page below: 
https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/tiva_arm/f/908/t/456894

For me and for the gentleman proposing that solution, it was a Windows registry issue, hence I only had to do the first step using the link provided in that answer, see: 
http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Volume1/Window8KeilDebuggerFix.htm

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue after I installed the [Stellaris ICDI drivers](http://www.ti.com/tool/stellaris_icdi_drivers):

> Tiva™ C Series evaluation and reference design kits provide an integrated In-Circuit Debug Interface (ICDI) which allows programming and debugging of the onboard C Series microcontroller. The ICDI can be used with the LM Flash Programmer as well as any of the Tiva-supported toolchains such as Texas Instruments’ Code Composer Studio. Only JTAG is supported. To use the ICDI, follow the instructions in the Quick Start document (literature number SPMU287) on this page to install the appropriate drivers on the host computer.

Answer (score 1):

in case you dont have drivers yet on devices.

solved the problem with this error.

http://www.ti.com/tool/STELLARIS_ICDI_DRIVERS

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

In periperipheral settings under debug->settings please select  connect under reset,
 reset after connect this will solve issues.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and after breaking my head for a couple of days finally found the solution.

My PC os was Windows 10 and I had the tiva c 123GH6PM board connected to it.

1. Go to Device manager and disable all the drivers for the device.
2. You will find the drivers Under the PORTS TAB

[image: image of windows menu]

3. Plugin the device now and the drivers are installed automatically,otherwise download the drivers and install them.
4. Reboot your PC , clear out the temp files
5. Plugin the device now , it works .Try a basic LED blink program for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: my JTAG debugger was functioning well on both my boards until I made a new software release. After spending hours at my new software, I realised that I had physically inverted the connector between the board and the JTAG debugger.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2**: Still had problems, the board would now program but it would jump out of debug immediately. All I had to do was remove an entry from registry and at long last, the board works consistently:-

1. Go to regedit:
   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers**
2. Remove entry:
   **C:\Keil\UV4\UV4.exe   REG_SZ   $IgnoreFreeLibrary<lmidk-agdi.dll>**

**EDIT 1**: I still had problems - for me, I had to also deselect 'Use debug driver' in the utilities tab of project options and select 'Stellaris ICDI'. I could then at least program the board.

**First try**: After messing about with LMFlashProgrammer and getting nowhere, I done the following and it unlocked the board:

1. Open CCS
2. Right-click project -> properties
3. Go to 'Debug'
4. Select 'Reset the target on a connect'
5. Rebuild and run debugger

P.S. Go and watch quantum leaps' tutorials on Youtube!